# How to display "edited this mins ago " in django

Tags: django

template.html
in my template i gave given the line below: where date_edit contains the current time. it always displays 0 minutes ago. how can i do it???

```
   {{date_edit|timesince}} ago
```

Comment: From the documentation "Minutes is the smallest unit used, and “0 minutes” will be returned for any date that is in the future relative to the comparison point.". - Read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

if date_edit stores the current time, it is normal for it to show 0 minutes. You should store the last edit time. You can achieve this by adding `auto_now=True` parameter in the DateTimeField attribute in your model. This way, it is updated only if you save the model.